# Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, asynchronous

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from "axios"
import { useEffect } from "react"
import { useState } from "react"

export function Profile (){
    const pathname = window.location.pathname
    const[data,setData] = useState([])
    const [loaded,hasloaded] = useState(false)

  let username = pathname.split("/")[1]

useEffect(()=>{
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/profile/getProfile', {
        "username":username
       })
       .then((res)=> setData(res.data))
})

  return (
    <div className='Wrapper'>
   
    <img/>

{loaded ? <h2>{data[0].username}</h2>:<h2>Loading</h2>}
  
    <img  />

    </div>
  )
}
```

axios it taking like 10 seconds to get the response is this normal? when i request on postman it takes like 1 second. also how can i render when i have recieved the data without  causing to many rerenders?

Comment: You haven't provided a dependency array to your `useEffect` so it runs on every render. Either add an empty array if you only want it to run once, or add the relevant dependency to trigger re-running it. see: [Tip: Optimizing Performance by Skipping Effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)

Answer (score 0):

When the dependency array for `useEffect` is `undefined` (instead of an empty array) then the effect runs on *every render*.  And within your `useEffect` you are updating state, which will trigger a re-render.  This means every render triggers a re-render.

It looks like you only want the effect to run once, when the component first loads.  For that, pass an empty dependency array to `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  axios.post('http://localhost:5000/profile/getProfile', {
    "username":username
  })
  .then((res)=> setData(res.data))
}, []); // <--- here
```